# what is the meaning of Volume[0]<=1?

Tags: mql4

how can I know the new candle in mql4 is starting?
what is the volume amount of the starting candle? ( starting candle means candle[0])
which of the following codes is true?
a) volume[0]==0

a) volume[0]<0

b) volume[0]<1

c) volume[0]<=1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to use Volume[0]

Use this code :

```
void OnTick()
{
 static datetime NewBar = 0;

 if(NewBar!=Time[0])
 {
  //do something...
 
  Newbar = Time[0];
 }
}
```